# How to set the instance for a value to be piped?

Tags: redcap

I have a form where I want to pipe a date into a descriptive  from a previous instance of a form.
The previous instance number will vary depending on criteria on the `[current-instance]` of the form.

I have created a calculation that determines the instance number of the variable to be piped called `[ins_cal]`. However, when I attempt to append this instance calculation to the variable, the value is missing.

In an example, if the instance of the date I want is calculated to be instance 3:
Using `[date][3]` works as intended. Using `[date][ins_cal]` returns `________`.
I have confirmed that the calculated field `[ins_cal]` is returning the number 3.

Any advice on how to progress/what may be missing?